# Добавить <hr> после <h2> с помощью .insertBefore()

Tags: jquery

Всем привет! Делаю тест, гуглил, вроде все ок, но hr не появляется...((( Подскажите пож что я делаю не так: нужно добавить hr после h2 с помощью .insertBefore()

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h3").addClass("sel");
  $("h3").insertBefore("<hr/>");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="id2">A</h2> 
<h3 id="id3">B</h3>
<h4 id="id4">C</h4>
```

В элемент попадаю, а hr не добавляется...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если посмотреть справку по функции [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) можно заметить, что именно делает эта функция:

> Insert every element in the set of matched elements before the target.

---

> Вставляет каждый элемент из набора перед элементов переданным в параметре

В данном случае в качестве target передается `<hr/>` - таким образом, при вызове функции создается такой элемент, перед ним добавляется `h3`, но, так как созданный элемент никуда не добавлен он и не показывается.

Для исправления можно использовать метод [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h3").addClass("sel");
  $("h3").before("<hr/>");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="id2">A</h2> 
<h3 id="id3">B</h3>
<h4 id="id4">C</h4>
```

Либо поменять местами параметры:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h3").addClass("sel");
  $("<hr/>").insertBefore("h3");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="id2">A</h2> 
<h3 id="id3">B</h3>
<h4 id="id4">C</h4>
```

Comment: поменял местами и все работает! Спасибо за помощь)